# R: Is there a way to select a column according to the current year?

Tags: r

Say you have a database like `gapminder` with the population per country. Even though the current year is 2021, you also have predictions for the following years to come.

```
location 2020.0  2021.0   2022.0 
Canada     5       7       9
China     23      34      54
Congo      1      2        3
```

and another database like this, `vaccins`

```
location     date       amount_of_vaccins 
Canada       2020-01-02       50            
China        2021-05-03       59          
Congo        2022-03-05       34
```

How can I merge the population of each country into the second database, but following the dates in the second database.

I managed to merge them by country like this:

```
merge(gapminder,vaccins, by = "location")
```

but I'm getting this

```
location     date       amount_of_vaccins  2020.0  2021.0  2022.0
Canada       2020-01-02       50             5        7       9
China        2021-05-03       59            23        34      54
Congo        2022-03-05       34             1        2      3
```

I'd like to have only a new variable giving the population of the country according to the year. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this with `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(!location, names_to = "date", values_to = "population") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(year = str_sub(date, 1, 4))

df2 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(year = str_sub(date, end = 4)) %>%
  dplyr::left_join(., df1, by = c("location", "year")) %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(date.y, year)) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(date = date.x)
```

Output

```
  location       date amount_of_vaccins population
1   Canada 2020-01-02                50          5
2    China 2021-05-03                59         34
3    Congo 2022-03-05                54          3
```

Data

```
df1 <-
  structure(
    list(
      location = c("Canada", "China", "Congo"),
      `2020.0` = c(5, 23, 1),
      `2021.0` = c(7, 34, 2),
      `2022.0` = c(9, 54, 3)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-3L)
  )

df2 <-
  structure(
    list(
      location = c("Canada", "China", "Congo"),
      date = c("2020-01-02",
               "2021-05-03", "2022-03-05"),
      amount_of_vaccins = c(50, 59, 54)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-3L)
  )
```

Comment: what if I'm trying to keep my original date (%Y%m%d)

Comment: @EmManuel I've updated the answer. Is that more of what you are looking for?